# using variable to define a char in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, char

I have a variable

```
filterSize = 3; %Size of the Filter;
```

I want to define a new char variable called size and assign it as

size = (filterSize x filterSize)

```
size='3x3';
```

but I want to use filterSize to do it to automate. size need to be char. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sprintf` to format a char containing variables

```
filterSize = 3;
sz = sprintf( '%dx%d', filterSize, filterSize );
```

You should avoid using `size` as a variable name because you're shadowing a commonly used in-built function.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment on using size as a variable name and for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem.

```
size_temp = [string(filterSize),'x',string(filterSize)];
a = convertStringsToChars(size_temp);
x=char(size_temp(1));
y=char(size_temp(2));
z=char(size_temp(3));
size = [x,y,z]
```

but as cris Luengo suggests in the comments
`size = [num2str(filterSize),'x', num2str(filterSize)]` is a better solution

Comment: It’s easier with [`num2str`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html): `[num2str(filterSize),'x', num2str(filterSize)]` is a char array.

Comment: Yes. yours is way better than mine. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

MATLAB has a function that precisely does what you asked for: 
.

call generic example :

evalin('base',['output = ',expression])

MATLAB funtion help reference :

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalin.html?s_tid=srchtitle_evalin_1

Assigning a value to new variable within your code has detractors and supporters, as it is a sharp tool that writes new code with code.

I had a couple of bitter discussions with a Mathworks forum member over different ways to use evalin.

When some one preaches not to do something because they call it sinful yet they keep doing it all the time, there's room for doubt that people in general should refrain to use evalin to concisely build new code within existing code.

I recommend you to ignore the last line in evalin help page where some one discourages from using evalin to exactly do what you need to in order to solve your question.

Hope it helps

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this is not what the OP is asking for, they want the output to be the literal char `'3x3'`, not the evaluation of some expression. Other than that, the opinionated stuff is a bit off-topic, there is a basis for avoiding `eval` when possible (it reduces performance, syntax checking, and readability, and increases security issues and bug potential). Yes it has its uses, this is not one of them because the functionality is not required anyway